# How do I look at the schema of a MySQL database on cPanel?

Tags: mysql

My question isn't so much programming specific, I guess, but more interface-specific.  My problem is that I need to look at the schema of some MySQL databases which are stored on a server that uses cPanel.  How do I just simply look at their table and column names remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have "phpMyAdmin", installed in the "databases" section of your cPanel. This will allow you to look at the schema of all databases the user you log in as can see.

In addition, this is probably more of a fitting question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks.  Now I have a board I can ask these kinds of question in.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

login to the cpanel and use phpmyadmin web application to view your database.